# Can't display an array from constructor in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular

Disclaimer: Just in case anybody notices, this IP address collection is just for a school project to minimize the effort. It's not going anywhere online.
Real question: I'm really desperate at this point. Just can't figure out the cause. I filtered an array(storyComments) that came from a service in constructor. Immediately after populating variable with that filtered array I console_logged to see if everything is correct. And it is. Array is there in console and filtered correctly. But can't display it for some reason. I'd like to mention that everything else populated within the constructor of the component is displaying correctly. So, what could be the issue here?

```
comments.component.html:
<mat-card-footer>
    <form [formGroup]="yourComment">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Ваш коментар:</mat-label>
          
          <input matInput formControlName="yourContent" [value]="yourOldComment?.content"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          
          <button mat-flat-button (click)="savingComment()" [disabled]="yourComment.invalid">Сачувај коментар!</button>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="yourOldComment">
            <button mat-flat-button (click)="deletingComment()"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
      <div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let comment of storyComments">
            <div>
                <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
                <p>{{comment.nickname}}</p>
                <p>{{comment.changed}}</p>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
  </mat-card-footer>


comments.component.ts:
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() storyId: number;
  yourOldComment: IComment;
  allComments: IComment[];
  storyComments: IComment[];
  ipAddress:string;
  yourComment = new FormGroup({
    yourContent: new FormControl("",[Validators.required]),
  })
  constructor(private commentsService:CommentsService,
    private ipAddressService:IpAddressService){
    let commentServiceData: Observable<IComment[]> = this.commentsService.getAllComments();
      let ipAddressServiceData: Observable<string> = this.ipAddressService.getIpAddress();
      forkJoin([commentServiceData,ipAddressServiceData])
        .subscribe(([data1,data2])=>{
          this.allComments = data1;
          this.ipAddress = data2;
          this.storyComments = data1.filter(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId);
          console.log(this.storyComments);
          this.yourOldComment = data1.find(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId && comment.ipAddress==this.ipAddress);
        },error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  savingComment(){
    let yourComment:IYourComment = {
          content : this.yourComment.get("yourContent").value,
          storyId : this.storyId,
          ipAddress :  this.ipAddress
        }
    if(!this.yourOldComment){
      this.commentsService.createComment(yourComment).subscribe(
            (response)=>{
              alert("Успешно сте додали коментар!");
            },
            (error)=>{
              console.error(error);
            }
          );
    }
    else {
      let commentId = this.yourOldComment.id;
      this.commentsService.updateComment(commentId,yourComment).subscribe(
        (response)=>{
          alert("Успешно сте изменили коментар!");
        },
        (error)=>{
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  deletingComment(){
    let commentId = this.yourOldComment.id;
    this.commentsService.deleteComment(commentId).subscribe(
      (response)=>{
        alert("Успешно сте избрисали свој коментар!");
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This is because at component rendering the data isn't there. You could store the observable in a variable like `storyComments$` and then apply an async pipe in the template like `storyComments$ | async`.

Comment: @derstauner, not. You can "subscribe" using pipe async or subscribe manually.

Comment: Yes, the async pipe does this. He could define (create) an observable returning from the forkjoin after filtering, etc the results. And he should subscribe to this observable in the template with the async pipe. I meant that in my comment. Because actually the comments array doesn't showing, because the data isn't there at first rendering.

Comment: Filtered comments are there actually! In the constructor right after I populated the variable with the filtered array I did console log. And filtered array is shown in console. Problem is, I can't drag it to front-end and loop it for some reason. But, it is there.

Comment: Maybe your filtered comments are not there during the rendering.
Your console.log is NOT executed in the constructor.
It's in a subscribe that is completely independant from the constructor. It's not a Promise.
It wll ve executed when the forkJoin emit. So maybe much much later after the constructor has finished its work.
If you put a console.log at the end of your constructor for example it will probably (can't be sure it depends on your observable) execute before the one in the subscribe.
But I'm not sure it's links to your problem.
You should try gaston chatelet proposition.

Comment: Valentin Roche, it is the case. I made console.log of this.storyComments bellow forkJoin and it indeed was listed before the one within subscribe of the forkJoin in the console. The one that was referring to the line bellow forkJoin was undefined, while next one in the console (one from subscribe) had elements inside. How to make the document to render after everything in the constructor (including that forkJoin) is done?

Answer (score 1):

Try forceing the detection of changes with `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(
    private commentsService:CommentsService,
    private ipAddressService:IpAddressService,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
) {

// your code
this.ipAddress = data2;
this.storyComments = data1.filter(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId);
this.cdref.detectChanges();    
// your code

}
```

Comment: Well, this solves my problem with yourOldComment variable that lagged for like minute or two. Now, in matter of second or two it appears. Great help, no doubt about it! But, what concerns me is the fact that storyComments are still missing and I can't figure out why, since console.log shows how there is an array with correctly filtered elements (which is still inside forkJoin.subscribe, but now together with everything else in the forkJoin it's inside of ngOnInit as well), yet there is none of storyComments on display. Just to clarify, I moved the whole forkJoin block to ngOnInit method.

Comment: ...and put this.cdref.detectChanges() at the end of the subscribe method of forkJoin, since in it I populate these bunch of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Mario, when we use ReactiveForms, in the input **not** use value, else give value to the FormControl.

```
.subscribe(([data1,data2])=>{
     ...
     //get the comment in a temporal variable
     const oldComent=data1.find(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId && 
             comment.ipAddress==this.ipAddress);
     //give value to the formControl using setValue
             this.yourComment.get('yourContent').setValue(oldComment?oldComment.content:'')
        },error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

And your .html simply

```
<form [formGroup]="yourComment">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Ваш коментар:</mat-label>
      <!--see not use [value]-->
      <input matInput formControlName="yourContent" />
    </mat-form-field>
    ...

    <!--see that to disable the button you use
          yourComment.get('yourContent').invalid
          // or simply 
          yourComment.invalid
          //a FormGroup is invalid if any formControl is invalid-->
     <button mat-flat-button (click)="savingComment()"
          [disabled]="yourComment.get('yourContent').invalid">Сачувај коментар!
     </button>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: YourComment isn't a problem. It's working fine. Problem are storyComments.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing the variable `storyComments` as an empty array before the constructor

```
storyComments: IComment[] = []
```

or initialize it before the `forkJoin` in the constructor:

```
this.storyComments = []
forkJoin(...
```

Comment: I did. It's in the sample.

Comment: No, you didn't. You just declare it, but it's undefined. `storyComments: IComment[];` its not the same as `storyComments: IComment[] = []`

Comment: Oh, you mean initializing... My bad. But, I already made it possible in some config setting to make sure that it allows variables to be declared but not initialized. How would initialization change anything?

Comment: If you initialize the variable, you ensure that at render time, the variable its an array so you can iterate witrh *ngFor

Comment: I mean, you can do it in the constructor as well, before the forkJoin.. the key is to reach the render process with an array, not an undefined variable

Comment: Same story. It does display needed array but only in console (which is called in the constructor immediately after populating the array). But there is something else strange going on. This yourOldComment which is also populated within the constructor of the child component, does not render immediately. I have to wait for like 2 minutes before it renders, while storyComments does not render at all. I have waited for like an hour. And again, storyComments are in the console. Just not in the html.

Comment: you can try with another aproach: ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. The main issue was absence of ngIf that prevents rendering if storyComments haven't arrived at time (or at all). Of course, a lot of help was suggestion to manually force change detection after populating variables so credit for that goes to gaston-chatelet. There is the final code (changed parts):

comments.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="storyComments">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let comment of storyComments">
            <div>
                <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
                <p>{{comment.nickname}}</p>
                <p>{{comment.changed}}</p>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
```

comments.component.ts:

```
constructor(private commentsService:CommentsService,
    private router:Router,
    private ipAddressService:IpAddressService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
    this.storyId = parseInt(this.router.url.split("/")[2]);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let commentServiceData: Observable<IComment[]> = this.commentsService.getAllComments();
      let ipAddressServiceData: Observable<string> = this.ipAddressService.getIpAddress();
      forkJoin([commentServiceData,ipAddressServiceData])
        .subscribe(([data1,data2])=>{
          this.ipAddress = data2;
          this.storyComments = data1.filter(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId);
          console.log(this.storyComments);
          this.yourOldComment = data1.find(comment=>comment.storyId==this.storyId && comment.ipAddress==data2);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        },error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }
```